# Monotouch change existing UIButtonBarItem's image

Tags: xamarin.ios

I would like to use the same UIBarButtonItem but change the Icon to another UIBarButtonSystemItem within the same instance. Is there a way to do this? Also is there a way to detect
which UIBarButtonSystemItem is being used?

```
var btn = UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.Play, null)
btn.?? = UIBarButtonSystemItem.Pause
```

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8739791/how-can-i-change-the-style-of-uibarbuttonitem-in-code

Answer (score 0):

choper pointed to me to a question that explained that I could not alter the image instance.
I basically followed the advice of that post and I toggle between two buttons(play and pause)